# How to use jasonkarns/bats-mock for stubbing curl command with variable arguments for shell script unit testing

Tags: shell, unit-testing, curl

I m trying to stub the curl for below code :

```
function network_client() {
  local method="$1"
  local url="$2"
  local data=""
  local response

  declare -a common_curl_options=()
  
  if [[ -n "${CERTIFICATE}" ]]; then
    common_curl_options+=("--cacert" "cert_file.pem")
  fi

  case "$method" in
    "POST")
      data="$3"
      common_curl_options+=("--request" "$method" "$url" "--header" 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' "--header" "Accept-Encoding: base64" "--data-urlencode" "$data")
      ;;
    "GET")
      common_curl_options+=("$url" "--header" "Authorization: Token token=\"$token\"")
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Unsupported HTTP method: $method"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac

  response=$(curl "${common_curl_options[@]}")
     
  if [ "$method" == "POST" ]; then
    token="$response"
  else
    result="$response"
  fi
}
```

And below code snippet call the above function "network_client"

```
function authenticate() {
  local jwt_token="${CIRCLE_OIDC_TOKEN_V2}"

  network_client "POST" "${URL}/authn-jwt/${SERVICE_ID}/${ACCOUNT}/authenticate" "jwt=$jwt_token"

  if [ -z "${token}" ]; then
    echo "Authentication Failed."
    exit 1
  else  
    echo "Authentication Successful."
  fi
}
```

I have tried below code to mock the curl but not working as expected

```
@test "network_client POST stubbed response" {
  _CURL_ARGS='${common_curl_options[@]}'
  stub curl \
      #"\"--request\" \"POST\" \"some_url\" \"--header\" \"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" \"--header\" \"Accept-Encoding: base64\" \"--data-urlencode\" \"some_data\" : echo 'received_dummy_token'"
      "${_CURL_ARGS} : echo 'received_dummy_token'" 

  run network_client "POST" "some_url" "some_data"
  assert_success
  assert_output 'received_dummy_token'

  unstub curl
}
```

Getting below error

network_client POST stubbed response
(in test file test/test.bats, line 122)
`"${_CURL_ARGS} : echo 'received_dummy_token'" ' failed with status 127
./test/test.bats: line 122: ${common_curl_options[@]} : echo 'received_dummy_token': command not found